# When enabling Clean URLs, test passes, but ticking & updating fails

Tags: uri

I have mod rewrite running fine and the test passed ont he CLean URLs page, however when I tick the box to 'Enable clean URLs' and click 'Save configuration', I get a message saying 'The configuration options have been saved.' however the box remains unticked and I get the same page below!

Any ideas why it is not enabling here?

Answer (score 0):

This has taken me a *long* time to resolve also. You need to set the relevant line in /sites/default/settings.php to

```
$GLOBALS['conf']['clean_url'] = 1;
```

Mine was set to zero. When I updated this, I realized that my server account didn't have permissions to change the `settings.php` file, and I suspect this is why it was not able to be updated by Drupal.

Hope this helps